# Browser doesn't render incoming POST request in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I'm working on a simple project where the user can register and login, **after logging in**, I want my website to load a new page for the user where only registered users can see.

After **authenticating** the user, I am sending the **new page** to the front-end from the back-end, so that the browser can render it and show it to the user.

But Instead of rendering the new page, my browser sends it via **Network** and doesn't render the new page, (i.e. still on the login page)

I can only reach my newly sent page from the inspect element **Network tab**, I can't see any change on the browser

[image]

I am new to web development, if I'm making a logical mistake please tell me.
Thank you in advance.

**Front-end**

```
loginButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault()
const userInfo = {
    username: loginUsername.value,
    password: loginPassword.value
}
$.post("/", userInfo, function(data) {
    console.log(data.token)
    $.post("/user", data, "text")
},"json")})
```

**Back-end**

```
router.post("/", (req,res) => {
jwt.verify(req.body.token, "dbpass123", function(err,decoded) {
    if(decoded){
       User.findById(decoded.id, function(err,user){
           if(user){
               res.status(200).send("Hello " + user.username + "!")
           }
       })
    }
}) })
```

Comment: Your very first paragraph explains that you're responding with a redirect. That's a message (over the network) to the browser that tells it to load another page.

Comment: @Pointy — No, it tells the browser to make another request and do with it whatever it was going to do with the original. If that is to load a new page, then it would load a new page. Otherwise … not. Which is likely the problem here. I've seen more than a few people wonder why a redirect response to an Ajax request doesn't cause the browser to navigate to a new page.

Comment: *squints at the wretched [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)* — That *is* the case here. I'll look for a duplicate.

Comment: @Quentin I was trying to use simple language; I can't see the posted graphics well enough to have any clue what's really going on.

Comment: @Pointy But it doesnt load anything. 
Also, when I say redirect I was not referencing to res.redirect() method, I am not responding with the redirect, If I use redirect I can't pass my JWT token, that's why I'm using a POST request, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @KeremDurdabak well the main problem is that I literally can barely see the images. It'd dramatically improve the question if you'd post the actual text of the HTTP Request and Response blocks you see in the browser Network tab, and explain what it is exactly that you're confused about.

Comment: @Quentin The image looks bad? Idk how that happened sorry.
Try this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKca9.png

Comment: @KeremDurdabak — Again: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You have `$.post("/user", token, "text")` … your JS **doesn't do anything with the response**. So you get the response, which you can see in the network tab, and your JS ignores it.

Comment: @Quentin I have added codes as you have suggested please consider looking it again

Comment: The answer is unchanged.

Comment: @Quentin How should I tell my client side JS to render the response on the browser, after it recieved?